# Installing an app in Shopware cloud shop leads to error

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

One of our customers wants to install one of our apps in his Shopware Cloud Shop, but only gets this error:

detail  'Client error: `GET https://api.shopware.com/swcloudadmin/pluginfiles/<app-name>?shopwareVersion=6.4.20.1&language=en-GB&domain=<customer-domain>` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{"success":false,"code":"CloudAdminException-21","title":"Error","description":"No suitable version could be found for t (truncated...)\n'

and  are stand-ins for the real things.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the  app is not compatible with the <6.4.20.1> version of Shopware.
When a compatible version of the app is uploaded, the app will be marked as compatible and the error should be gone.